# encrypt files by external GPG public key tools?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, batch-file, gpg, pgp

how i can encrypt files by eternal GPG public key ?

for example user `A` generate public key `A.pub` and sent to me `A.pub` and you need from me to encrypt file by `a.pub` and sent it to you

how i can do that ? please explain it step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do it follow the following steps :-

1- `gpg --import "d:\mohammad.txt"`

2-`gpg --recipient "mohammad" --output "d:\port.txt.gpg" --encrypt "d:\port.txt"`